# Anyone know why this code always returns 33.80?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    double tempc;
    printf("Enter your temperature (Celsius):\n");
    scanf("%f", &tempc);
    printf("Your temperature in Fahrenheit is %.2f", (1.8 + tempc + 32));
}
```

No matter what input I give to `tempc` it always prints `33.80`? I am very confused.

Comment: Your compiler should tell you the reason: https://godbolt.org/z/P5fnzzvzr `scanf` needs `%lf` to read a `double`.

Comment: `scanf("%f", &tempc);` ==> `scanf("%lf", &tempc);` and turn up the warnings to 11.

Comment: Aside: and fix the calculation error to be `1.8 * tempc + 32`

Comment: Enable warnings and the compiler will tell you about the problem. For GCC/Clang for example: `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: And add `-Werror`; then you won't by tempted to run buggy code.